# Who's the child and her mother that can "talk to flowers" in Ruins?

Tags: marvel, comics, character-identification, ruins

In *[Ruins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruins_(comics))* (1995), a Marvel Comics limited series, there is a child who says that she has a mother that "talks to flowers". Who's the child and who is her mother?

I was able to identify many of the characters referred to in *Ruins* but not this one. This part also wasn't mentioned in the Wikipedia plot summary for *Ruins*. I searched for Marvel comics characters that have a "talking to plants" ability but have only found Dryad and Klara Plast, and they both seem to have been introduced after *Ruins* was published.

The page where the character appears and mentions her mother is below:

<sup>Click on image below to view original, full-sized image.</sup>
[image: screencap of comics page described above]

Comment: Lots of non-superheros [talk to flowers](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/gardening/5080991/Prince-of-Wales-talked-to-plants-scientists-test-if-it-works.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The girl was [just a girl](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LivingProp). According to my good friend, Ruins artist [Terese Nielsen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terese_Nielsen), she was inserted into the plot in order to demonstrate Phil Sheldon's frame of mind.

> **Q:** ***In Ruins, who was the little girl?***
>
> **[TN](https://twitter.com/tnielsenart/status/746819365845110784)**:  *The model was our daughter, **the character was a random little girl
> that could tell he needed a flower and a hug.***